# ProgressDialog is not shown in the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

```
Document doc = new Obtainer(context, uri).execute().get();
```

This code in the activity class renders the Obtainer(which extends AsyncTask) which gets the xml document from the url. This is the onPreExecute method:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Pre execute began");
        exception = null;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading started");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        System.out.println("Preexecute end");
        dialog.show();
    }
```

context is set in the Constructor:

```
public Obtainer(Context c, String addr) {
    context = c;
    address = addr;
}
```

During the runtime I can see in the console output both "Pre execute began" and "Preexecute end" but the progress dialog is not shown. What is the probleM?

Comment: Your code is looked fine, just to know what is context in Document doc = new Obtainer(context, uri).execute().get();? Try to put <your activityName>.this instead of context...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works for me:

```
class Obtainer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(App.this); // App - your main activity class
        dialog.setMessage("Please, wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // ... 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

And in your main activity class method call

```
new Obtainer().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

What Context are you passing when you create your Obtainer (AsyncTask subclass)?

If you are using the Application context via getApplicationContext(), it can not be used to create a Dialog (or any View for that matter).  You need to pass it a Context that can create Views.

"If you're in the habit of using your application context (from a call to getApplicationContext(), for example) in places where you need a Context to create views, it's only a matter of time until you find a case where things don't work quite like you would want or expect."

From: [https://plus.google.com/107708120842840792570/posts/VTeRBsAeyTi](http://See%3a%20https://plus.google.com/107708120842840792570/posts/VTeRBsAeyTi)